# $G=\big<a, b: a^4=1=b^2 \quad and\quad ab=ba^{-1}\big>$ How can we know $ba^2=a^2b$ $\quad$and $ba^3=a^2ba?$

Tags: group-theory

> let $G$ be the dihedral group $D(4)$:
>   $$G=\big<a, b: a^4=1=b^2 \quad and\quad ab=ba^{-1}\big>$$
>   Let $N$ be the subgroup generated by $a^2,$ so that $N$ consists of the two
>   elements $1$ and $a^2.$ Then $N$ is a normal subgroup of G. This may be seen
>   in a variety of ways, one way being to enumerate the four left cosets of N
>   in G as:
>
> $$1N=\{1,a^2\}, bN=\{b,ba^2\}, aN=\{a,a^3\}, 
>  baN=\{ba,ba^3\}$$
>
> > Since $ba^2=a^2b$ $\quad$and $ba^3=a^2ba$$\qquad$, it is easy to see that each of these is a
> >     right coset:
>
> $1N=N1, bN=Nb, aN=Na, baN=Nba.$

Here I didn't understand the part starting with "since". How did we show $ba^2=a^2b$ $\quad$and $ba^3=a^2ba$$\qquad$ ?And also how did we know N is normal subgroup of G in the first place? How can we check that?

Comment: $ab=ba^{-1} \Rightarrow a^2b =aab = aba^{-1}=ba^{-2}=ba^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the second relation, multiplying on the left by $b$ gives
$$
bab = a^{-1}
$$
Squaring this, remembering that $b^2 = 1$, gives 
$$
ba^2b = a^{-2}
$$
Now $a^2 = a^{-2}$ because $a^4 = 1$, so this can be rewritten
$$
ba^2 b = a^2
$$
Once more right-multiply by $b$ to get 
$$
ba^2 = a^2b.
$$

Do similar stuff to get the other relation you're confused by. Practice makes perfect.

Comment: Aren't there any other left cosets of N in G apart from these four cosets? For example abN? @John Hughes

Comment: $ab=ba^3$. So $abN=baN$, the fourth coset in your list.

Comment: What Donald said. :)

Comment: How can I be sure that I wrote all the left cosets? I mean yes I can check one by one, but how can I be sure that this is the complete list or how to check in case I forgot some of them? @JohnHughes

Comment: The order of the group divided by order of the subgroup will give the number of cosets & they will form a partition of the group. If the left & right cosets coincide then the subgroup is normal.

Answer (score 2):

In the definition of $G$ you have that
$$
a^4=1 \ \text{and} \ ab=ba^{-1}
$$
so
$$
a^3=a^{-1}\Rightarrow a^2=a^{-2}
$$
This means that
$$
a^2b=aab=aba^{-1}=ba^{-2}=ba^2.
$$
Furthermore
$$
ba^3=ba^{2}a=a^2ba.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$a^{-1}=a^3$ so $\color{blue}{ab=ba^3}$. And we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
a^2b=a \color{blue}{ab}=a\color{blue}{ba^3}=\color{blue}{ab}a^3=\color{blue}{ba^3}a^3 =ba^2.
\end{eqnarray*}
We cannot conclude that $N$ is normal until we have shown that its cosets are left & right cosets.

Comment: Oh, okay. I think instead of THEN, they should have stated that "we will show".